# Python Requests POST / Upload Image File

Tags: python, post, python-requests

How can I os.remove() this image after it has been uploaded? I believe that I need to close it somehow.

```
import requests, os

imageFile = "test.jpg"

myobj = {'key': 'key', 'submit':'yes'}
up = {'fileToUpload':(imageFile, open(imageFile, 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data')}
r = requests.post('https://website/uploadfile.php', files=up, data = myobj)
sendTo = r.text
os.remove(imageFile)
```

The above generates:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restructure your code so that you are using a context manager:

```
import requests, os

imageFile = "test.jpg"

myobj = {'key': 'key', 'submit':'yes'}
with open(imageFile, "rb") as im:
    up = {'fileToUpload':(imageFile, im, 'multipart/form-data')}
    r = requests.post('https://website/uploadfile.php', files=up, data = myobj)
    sendTo = r.text
os.remove(imageFile)
```

When you exit the `with` block, the file will automatically be closed, the lock will be released, and you can then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You never closed the file after opening.

Try:

```
import requests, os

imageFile = "test.jpg"

with open(imageFile, 'rb') as f:
    myobj = {'key': 'key', 'submit':'yes'}
    up = {'fileToUpload':(imageFile, f, 'multipart/form-data')}
    r = requests.post('https://website/uploadfile.php', files=up, data = myobj)
    sendTo = r.text

os.remove(imageFile)
```